# Upgrading LogStash Log4j configuration to Log4j2

Tags: spring-boot, log4j, log4j2, properties-file

I am trying to migrate my Spring Boot app from Log4j to Log4j 2. I understand the Log4j 2 changed the syntax of `.properties` configurations from the original Log4j.

Here is a snippet of my original Log4j configuration:

```
log4j.appender.logstash=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender
log4j.appender.logstash.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logstash.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p %c {2} %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.logstash.Port=4560
log4j.appender.logstash.RemoteHost=logs.example.com
log4j.appender.logstash.ReconnectionDelay=10000
```

and here is what I updated it to, for Log4j 2:

```
appender.logstash.type=SocketAppender # Or 'Socket'
appender.logstash.name=logStash
appender.logstash.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.logstash.layout.pattern=%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p %c {2} %x - %m%n
appender.logstash.host=logs.example.com
appender.logstash.port=4560
appender.logstash.reconnectionDelayMillis=10000
```

However, when I do this, my console and file appenders work just fine,  but the LogStash appender throws a `Broken pipe` error.

I've looked into this an it seems that I may need to wrap the `SocketAppender` in an `AsyncAppender` and pointing the `ref` towards my `logStash SocketAppender` (as in [this documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html)), but then I get exceptions that the properties do not exist:
appender.async.type=Async
appender.async.ref=logStash # Or 'refs', 'appender-ref', etc.

Is a `.properties` file not the way to go for Async Socket Appenders?  I could use some help in migrating from Log4j 1 to 2 via this properties file.

Comment: It appears to be the known issue. You should probably update your logstash-log4j2 to the newer release - according to this link: https://github.com/jurmous/logstash-log4j2/issues/3.

Comment: Yep that's it.  If you wouldn't mind posting that as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a problem in older releases of logstash-log4j2. It was fixed in release 3.2. The newer release may be taken from this [link](https://github.com/jurmous/logstash-log4j2/releases/).

Besides, the appender name is not **SocketAppender** but **Socket** - that is according to the [documentation example](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#SocketAppender), which uses the name **Socket** in log4j2.xml:

```
<Appenders>
    <Socket name="socket" host="localhost" port="9500">
      <SerializedLayout />
    </Socket>
</Appenders>
```

I suppose you should change you log4j2.properties accordingly:

```
appender.logstash.type=Socket
appender.logstash.name=logStash
appender.logstash.layout.type=PatternLayout
...
```

I know that this is the matter of habit and "do-not-change-the-working-code" approach but may be it worth to move to xml configuration format while migrating to log4j2, since vast of the examples in the documentation are using it.

Comment: I tried that, still no luck :-\  I think you have a point about moving to XML though, maybe it's worth moving to it.

Comment: No luck with XML approach either.